# Batch script to create new folder under every existing subfolder

Tags: batch-file, directory

Right now my below script creates folders in everything I enter a new client name. The problem is that there are hundreds of existing folders I want to create these below folders in. I was wondering if there was a way to loop through all the existing folders without having to specify each route client folder and just wildcard it to do all of them at once under the directory `N:\"Test Installations"`

Any help would be appreciated

```
set Client_Name="Test"

md N:\"Test Installations"\%Client_Name%\Implementation\CAT\
md N:\"Test Installations"\%Client_Name%\Implementation\CAT\Archive
md N:\"Test Installations"\%Client_Name%\Implementation\PROD\
md N:\"Test Installations"\%Client_Name%\Implementation\PROD\Archive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
dir /s /b /o:n /ad > dir.txt
for /F %i in (dir.txt) do mkdir "%i\newdir"
```

I've given it a quick test and it works fine.

I should say you need to change the mkdir to the create name of the new directory you want to create.

Comment: why not  directly `for /F "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /s /b /o:n /ad') do mkdir "%i\newdir"` ?

Comment: I'm sure there are any number of ways to do the above.